# Should I ask what I should prepare for the test?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, email, work-experience, test

I applied for a job that I have no previous experience with, and have passed the screening email round. The email says that I will have to analyze the company's website, which in my opinion it's distinctly related to the job description in their website or in Wikipedia, but apparently the only thing I should be familiar with in order to pass the test.

Should I ask the recruiter what I should prepare in order to do the test successfully? I want them to know that I really want to learn, but will this show that I'm not qualified?

The job is business analyst, if that matters.

Please help me tag this question properly. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere because "it's distinctly related to the job description in their website or in Wikipedia". This confuses me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's bad practice to apply for a job you don't know how to do. But if you must then there's an old adage which has gotten many people lucrative careers.

'Fake it until you break it.'

So don't ask the question, just try and play it by ear and talk your way through using long technical sounding words and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't comment on whether or not to ask the recruiter what to prepare for the test, but I could tell you that since they asked you to analyze the 'company website', that's your best bet.

There are a few things you could focus on:

- The company's vision(what they say they are and they want to achieve)
- The company's products over the past few years
- Clients of the company, prepare any important ones
- Recent news
- The listing you have and applied for, what they expect from somebody in your position.
- I don't know about the business world, but in the world of programming, you are also expected to know about people who have made significant contributions to the field, such as Don Knuth or Linus Torvalds.